# Views calender missing menu tabs

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I cannot get my Views calendar to have the tabs (e.g. Month,Week,Day,Year) in the upper left corner like the below image:

[image]

How do I get those tabs to appear?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is experiencing the same problem:

1) Go to each display's Page Settings.
2) Set the Path $path/week, $path/month, etc., where $path the respective path you have in the month display.
3) Set the Menu Type in Menu to Menu Tab.

Save view and clear caches.

Comment: Done. Still doesn't work. I think that's a bug in the module. Sometimes, those tabs don't work. Ref: https://www.drupal.org/node/1265590